# What's the difference between TabPanel and TabLayoutPanel in GWT

Tags: java, gwt

What's the difference between TabPanel and TabLayoutPanel in GWT? I can't find the answer in Google and it is difficult to understand reading docs

Answer (score 11):

`TabLayoutPanel` is a *layout panel*: it's sized from the outside-in, it has to be given explicit dimensions and be notified when they changed (`RequiresResize`), and similarly will resize its children and notify them when it does so (`ProvidesResize`).

`TabPanel` is not; it's sized from the inside-out: it'll resize itself depending on the size of the widget in the selected tab.

Comment: Also note that TabLayoutPanel only works in Standards Mode while the TabPanel is supposed to be only used in QuirksMode.

Comment: is it only about resizing? when should I use one and when another?

Comment: @damluar: See the answer provided by me

Answer (score 10):

Addition to what Thomas is saying

In GWT, To layout the widgets in the screen there are two kind of panels: `Panels` ***( Eg: TabPanel )*** and `Layout Panels` ***( Eg: TabLayoutPanel )***

### Panels or Non-layout panels

These panels (TabPanel, DockPanel, Horizontal panel, Vertical Panel, AbsolutePanel ... ) allow you to layout widgets in an explicit manner. It will render the widgets as imagined ( *provided correct imagination* ;) ). Its child widgets are ***not*** automatically resized when the browser resizes.

### Layout panels

These Panels (TabLayoutPanel, DockLayoutPanel, ScrollPanel, FlexTable, SplitLayoutPanel... ) allow you to layout widgets in the explicit manner but also resize the child widget when the browser resizes as each of them implements `RequiresResize` and/or `providesResize` provided you maintain Layout panels hierarchy throughout and provide the size of panels and widgets in percentages.

**Sources:**  GWT Docs and Personal Experience